# Visual Studio Quick actions and Refactorings Question

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm learning C# and I use Visual Studio 2017.

I'm doing some simple exercises and I've noticed that VS is giving me 
suggestions that I didn't find in my notes. It doesn't give me an error or warning. I just trying to find the difference.

I give:

```
Num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

and it suggests:

```
Num = Convert.ToInt32(value: Console.ReadLine());
```

or

I give:

```
Console.WriteLine("The number x 100 is {0}", Num * 100);
```

And it suggests:

```
Console.WriteLine("The number x 100 is {0}", arg0: Num * 100);
```

What difference does it make and is it important?

Comment: Looks like [named arguments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/named-and-optional-arguments#named-arguments).

Comment: Did you installed some extensions or something? My VS is not suggesting to use named parameters.

Comment: `named parameters` performs better than normal one, if there is overload of the same method or optional parameters are there.

Comment: I think Resharper might suggest using named parameters.

Comment: Are you using Reshaper? there is a specific setting for this.

Comment: I see now, it doesn't give anything until you manually call "Quick actions and Refactorings". They are not suggestions, just possible quick actions you can do with that part of code.

Comment: No I'm not using Reshaper :) but I think Uwe's Link answers my question.

Comment: It tells you what it is, not why VS is applying it.

Comment: So if I understand it properlly its a "Tag" of sort so you know what this part of code is all about. SeM +1

Comment: @gmonster1st It's more like, if you have some code, there are actions that are widely used by programmers, so VS added some actions, quickly add names for arguments to your method call (in your case), or extract full property from automated property, etc. In other hand, suggestions will appear inside _"Error List -> Messages"_ and probably will be highlighted.

Comment: Thank you Guys I appreciate all your comments and you Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments underneath the question:

> Looks like named arguments. – Uwe Keim
>
> named parameters performs better than normal one, if there is overload
>   of the same method or optional parameters are there. – Kaushik
>
> I see now, it doesn't give anything until you manually call "Quick
>   actions and Refactorings". They are not suggestions, just possible
>   quick actions you can do with that part of code. – SeM
>
> @gmonster1st It's more like, if you have some code, there are actions
>   that are widely used by programmers, so VS added some actions, quickly
>   add names for arguments to your method call (in your case), or extract
>   full property from automated property, etc. In other hand, suggestions
>   will appear inside "Error List -> Messages" and probably will be
>   highlighted. – SeM

This solved the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Named arguments are essential when you have optional parameters and you want to assign values only to few of them.
Among the examples you reported, there is no difference except for the syntax.